# Stream videos securely using AWS CloudFront

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I am attempting to serve paid videos to the users of my website, which is using php and is hosted on AWS.

I was wondering if:
1) anyone has successfully managed to serve video content through CloudFront securely? No matter what I try, FlashDownloadPlayer has managed to download the video.
2) will the video I upload automatically play in all devices/platforms regardless of input raw file I use ? I wasn't able to confirm this through AWS documentation.

Regardless, any ideas to make video downloading extremely difficult (atleast not through flashDownloadPlayer) would really be appreciated.
My videos are stored in AWS S3.

Thanks!

Comment: Only RMTP streaming is secured while others can be downloaded via any chrome / ff extension

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this through Cloudfront and have it be just as fast as Youtube, with a CDN on a similar scale as Google. The difference being you can make Cloudfront private and encrypted as you mention. For example, we host dozens of confidential online videos behind our business Intranet and Extranet site. Obviously the site is password protected, and the videos needed to be private.  Cloudfront let's you encrypt the video and embed inside a video player such as JWPlayer. This was the only way we could pass our security audit, while still serving massive video content and have it be fast. It sounds quite involved, but we followed a great guide in [this tutorial](https://centroy.com/blog/secure-video-alternative-to-youtube) and got this going in a few hours. Very straight forward.

https://centroy.com/blog/secure-video-alternative-to-youtube

Comment: This link is broken. Do you still have this blog?